# How to wrap my head around Object Oriented Design

Tags: java, oop, generics, software-design

Object oriented design is a pretty neat concept, but I'm struggling on how to wrap my head around most of its facets. I think the key to a good object oriented design is having a good grasp on how to look at it. I usually look at object-oriented this way:

Classes are Real-world entities or objects

Instance Fields are entity's attributes, ('has A')

Methods are like actions, verbs, Entity's abilities

Interfaces are like abilities that you can imbue on an object. It could also be an 'is A or can do' relationship whose implementations are not set in stone. Superman is a Krypton, being a Kryptonian comes with a set of special abilities, like flying, freeze-breath, etc. Superman fly different from Green Lantern and Goku and especially Batman, that is why Flight as interface is probably a good idea if you're creating a Fictional Universe.

```
public class SuperMan extends Man implements Kryptonian{}

public interface Kryptonian extends Flight, FreezeBreath{
    public void fly();
    public void coolBreath();
}
```

Problem comes along when you add Generics into the mix? Because the given type parameters somehow creates a contract between the class/interface and the type.

```
public interface Flight<T>{
     public void fly(T t);
}
```

In this example, Flight is coupled with a T, T could be a superhero a bird or anything that can fly.But is that really how I should imagine it? Because that seems like the same as what plain interfaces do? Although, a parameterized interface is still an interface, the coupling with the type T is what really bothers me. Moreover, things also get complicated when you add bounded restriction on the parameter type.

```
public class Pidgey<T extends Bird> implements Flight<T>{}
```

what real-world concrete object can you identify T with? The above example is pretty wrong, although using the class parameter to also restrict the type of Flight is probably a good design, because Flight is still independent enough that other classes could still use it without any restriction. But the example itself is wrong. Pidgey is a Bird that can fly, but what what could T be? Well, T could be anything, it could be another object or abilities. The question is what are its implications, why put T there? What are real-world examples of doing so?

It's easy to understand when you talk about collections, since collections are like containers. You can create a wide variety of containers that holds different kinds of objects.

```
public class WaterBottle<T extends Liquid> implements UniqueCap{}
```

But I've seen Generics being used not just on a container-like objects? How could one design such objects, what did they consider?

Comment: Technically Superman's abilities depend on where he is.

Comment: Where did you see this use of generics?

Comment: In the spirit of objects representing "real things" (which I don't think is really what object orient programming is), you could always have something like `public interface Flock<T extends Bird>` where the flock is a group of birds--this is still a container (essentially) though.

Comment: This question is too broad and too diffuse.  There is no way to succinctly address this question as stated.  Try breaking it up into smaller questions each with a specific focus.

Comment: In your first example, I'd say T could represent the type of fuel or energy source used to fly.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk that's a valid point. T could be the fuel. I can start with that. But it could also be a property, but we could also make an argument to add Fuel as T so that we have something to identify flight with depending on what we're building. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, implementing it as a generic simply allows for greater flexibility to account for the type of fuel not always being the same, assuming your fuel is represented by its own class with particular properties.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk that actually makes total sense! That is why it's called generics. So it's safe to say, that say, for designing an interface we should take into account if there's a property that frequently change depending on the requirements, that's when we decide to declare it as a type parameter?

Comment: If its type changes depending on the requirements, yep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analogies to the various features in OOP are definitely valid. Generics definitely make the most sense when talking about collections/containers/Hashmaps. They do have their uses in other places, though. For example, if a bank wants to process notes in many currencies, they can write
    public class moneyProcessor

However, generics **aren't required**. In the context of your `Flight` interface, there wouldn't be much of a reason to use generics. Which brings me to another point:

**Just because someone else does something one way doesn't mean you have to do it that way.** OOP is very flexible for a reason. There's always more than one correct way. If a method takes an `Object` as a parameter, it's not the end of the world. Just make sure you can read it later. :)

Edit: and that others can read it too.

Answer (score 0):

Its convention to use T when dealing with generics. it makes code readable as others reading your code will immediately know you're referring to a generic and nothing specific